# Integer to String in SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT
      l_i.lead_name AS name,
      l_i.lead_source AS lead_source,
      l_i.lead_source_detail AS lead_source_detail,
      l_i.campaign_source_name AS campaign_source,
      l_i.title AS title,
      l_i.industry AS industry,
     -- l_i.combined_lead_score AS combined_lead_score,
```

I want to Select l_i.combined_lead_score but it doesn't allow because it is int and the rest are text

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  The type of one column has no bearing on the types of other columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CAST function like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    l_i.lead_name AS name,
    l_i.lead_source AS lead_source,
    l_i.lead_source_detail AS lead_source_detail,
    l_i.campaign_source_name AS campaign_source,
    l_i.title AS title,
    l_i.industry AS industry,
    CAST(l_i.combined_lead_score as varchar(10)) AS combined_lead_score,
```